Is the data generated by Compress unique?
Is the data generated by the Compress function in Mathematica unique? I’m considering using it to identify duplicates because it reduces memory usage significantly, but I’m concerned that the compressed data might not be unique (similar to a hash function).
Does anyone know if Compress guarantees uniqueness or if there are potential collisions?

Since it can be uncompressed again to retrieve the original expression, it must be unique

ie Compress is a bijective function hence it is unique
